# HTML5 Text above image with background canvas not shown

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

What elements are using: BACKGROUND IMAGE + IMAGE(shape) + TEXT in canvas

Problem: Not showing text above a image of background in canvas.

What I expected: Show a text above of image with background image of color.

What I have: If removed image `makeShape()` function it will show text. Notice: image function have a background color.

---

This is a HTML form code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Canvas text above picture</title>    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            canvas {
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<form>
<p>
<label for="backgroundColor">Text font:</label>
<select id="backgroundColor">
<option value="white" selected="selected">White</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="txt">Text font:</label>
<textarea id="txt" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
</p>

<p>
<input type="button" id="previewButton" value="Preview">
</p>
</form>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
        <script src="canvasshirt.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

A `canvasshirt.js` code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("previewButton");
    button.onclick = previewHandler;
}

function previewHandler() {

    var ca = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var co = ca.getContext("2d");

    var bgcolor = document.getElementById("backgroundColor");
    var index = bgcolor.selectedIndex;
    var fgColor = bgcolor[index].value;

    var text = document.getElementById("txt").value;

    drawText(co, text); // ! - this should show text above of drawBckg() function

    drawBckg(ca, co, 600, 500, fgColor); // this draw a background of picture below of text
}


function drawBckg(ca, co, w, h, color)
{
    makeShape(co);

    co.fillStyle = color;
    co.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
}

function makeShape(co)
{
    var shapeimg = new Image();

    shapeimg.src = "shape2.png";

    shapeimg.onload = function() {
        co.drawImage(shapeimg, 170, 10, 233, 350);
    }
}

function drawText(co, text)
{
    co.font = " 13px Arial";
    //co.font = "bold 1em sans-serif";
    co.textAlign = "left";
    co.fillText(text, 20, 40);
}
```

FIXATION TRY...

When is changing of function sorting of source code it will result below:

```
drawBckg(ca, co, 600, 500, fgColor);
drawText(co, text);
```

Image of example (text is below of image):

[image: Blue text is below of <code>makeShape()</code> picture with turned off background]

Comment: You're drawing in the wrong order. Each time you draw something to the canvas, it draws it ON TOP of whatever is in that position. Draw the text AFTER you draw the background.

Comment: You say first draw, Text than, image and than background of image? But this is not fixed, look below answered question. Tried.

Comment: So you are drawing the image after it loads, which is asynchronous. You'll have to create a callback to draw the text after it draws the image (in the `shapeimg.onload` event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drawBckg(ca, co, 600, 500, bgcolor, function(){
    drawText(co, text, fgColor);
});
```

...

```
function drawBckg(ca, co, w, h, color, callback)
{
    makeShape(co, callback);

    co.fillStyle = color;
    co.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    callback();  // draw the text here as a fallback if the image doesn't load
}

function makeShape(co, callback)
{
    var shapeimg = new Image();

    shapeimg.src = "shape2.png";

    shapeimg.onload = function() {
        co.drawImage(shapeimg, 170, 10, 233, 350);
        callback();  // draw the text after drawing the image.
    }
}
```

Comment: Not fixed. I'm setting drawBckg() function BEFORE drawText. Not fixed. Shape of Image `makeShape()` is ABOVE of `drawText()`. I'm trying remove `co.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);` but it remove background and SHOW TEXT above background but not above of SHAPE image. I will upload an a image.

Comment: Tryied. Putted a code. Works! Thank you. Callback function is resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

First when a drawing a object it must will be revert on new state or it will owerwritten image on same images. This is function `co.restore()`:

```
function drawBckg(ca, co, w, h, color)
{
    co.restore();

    makeShape(co);
}
```

But, my failed is putting inside onload function:

```
function makeShape(co)
{
    var shapeimg = new Image();

    shapeimg.src = "shape2.png";

    shapeimg.onload = function() {  // <-- remove
    co.drawImage(shapeimg, 170, 10, 233, 350);
    }   // <-- remove
}
```

This will load, show below of picture because it FIRSTLY LOADED. Remove onload to loaded drawImage normally:

```
function makeShape(co)
{
    var shapeimg = new Image();

    shapeimg.src = "shape2.png";

    co.drawImage(shapeimg, 170, 10, 233, 350); // <-- this
}
```

Now it works!